# Filter array in React Native

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, filter

I try to filter array. I need "live filtering" when a user types something in search input in React Native, but I do it like I usually do filter in React. Something goes wrong.
Can you take a look and tell me where is a mistake? Now I have error: `undefined is not an object (this.state.inputValue.trim)` I think that maybe I should do some another way for a filter?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { View, Image, TouchableOpacity, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import { TopName, BottomName, TitleLedger } from '../common/text';
import styles from './style';

const rows = [{
  "img": require('../../assets/avatar.png'),
  "name": "Johnny",
  "nick": "@johny",
},{
  "img": require('../../assets/avatar.png'),
  "name": "Johnny",
  "nick": "@johny",
},{
  "img": require('../../assets/avatar.png'),
  "name": "Alex",
  "nick": "@alex",
},{
  "img": require('../../assets/avatar.png'),
  "name": "Johnny",
  "nick": "@johny",
}];

export default class Payment extends Component {
    state={
        inputValue: ''
    }
    onChangeHandler = (e)=> {
         this.setState({inputValue: e.target.value})
         console.log(e.target.value, 'value')
     }
  render() {
    const inputValueLet = this.state.inputValue.trim().toLowerCase();
    let rowsNew = [];
    if(rows.length>0){
            rowsNew = rows.filter(row => {
                return row.name.toLowerCase().match( inputValueLet )
            });
        }
    const { navigator } = this.props;
    const dataRow = rowsNew.map((row, index) => {
            return (
              <View style={styles.content}>
              <Image source={row.img} style={styles.avatar}/>
              <View key={index} id={index} style={styles.operation}>
                <View style={styles.wrapper}>
                  <View style={styles.topName}>
                    <TopName label={row.name} />
                  </View>
                  <View style={styles.bottomName}>
                    <BottomName label={row.nick} />
                  </View>
                </View>
              </View>
              </View>
            )
          })
    return (
        <View>
          <View>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.searchBar}
              type="text"
              value={this.state.inputValue}
              onChange={this.onChangeHandler}
              placeholder='Search'
              />
          </View>
        <View style={styles.container}>
            {dataRow}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: There's already a correct answer, but in addition I point you that you could write: `const rowsNew = rows.filter(row => row.name.toLowerCase().match(inputValueLet);` directly instead of that existing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `event.target.value` in react native `TextInput#onChange`. Use `event.nativeEvent.text` or [`onChangeText` event](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#onchangetext) where you get text as callback argument.

```
<TextInput
          style={styles.searchBar}
          type="text"
          value={this.state.inputValue}
          onChangeText={inputValue => this.setState({ inputValue })}
          placeholder='Search'
          />
```

Answer (score 0):

`inputValue` in your `state` is declared as string `''`.

```
state = {
     inputValue: ''
}
```

To resolve error `undefined is not an object (this.state.inputValue.trim)`.

I think you should declare `inputValue` as object :

```
state = {
     inputValue: {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onChange={(e)=>{setSearch(e.target.value)}}
```

users.filter(item=>item.name.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(search.toLocaleLowerCase())).map((item)=>

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33693533)